# Automatically changing dates to YYYYMMDD format with Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I'm making an error-proof worksheet for employees in my area. Our system needs to be fed through an excel worksheet. Along with other validations I've already added, I need to convert birthday dates to the format `YYYYMMDD` as string/number because swiching it on Excel with custom formats that drops an error on the system when uploaded (I guess it still reads dates as DD/MM/YYYY).

So I'm trying to use `Worksheet_Change()` so when the user inputs any date as `DD/MM/YYYY` it automatically converts is as the required result.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("G")) Is Nothing Then

    On Error Resume Next

    fecnacadd = Target.Address
    fecnac = Target.Value

    fecnacadd = Format(fecnac, "yyyymmdd")

    Columns("G").NumberFormat = "General"

End If
```

This code oddly works when debugging (shows the 'YYYYMMDD' correctly) but running it as is, gets the macro in a loop (?) for 10 seconds and it deletes the content in the cell.

Any hints in my code are appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are causing an infinite loop by changing the value of the cell that is in column `G` which causes this code to run again. Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of this subroutine and toggle that back to `True` at the end.

Comment: You'll have to disable worksheet events during your processing of the event you catch, in order to avoid creating an infinite (or at least long running) loop. Set `Application.EnableEvents = False` and don't forget to re-enable it when you're done.

Comment: Why `On Error Resume Next`?  If you have an expected error, you should test for it. Otherwise, you may miss errors that you should be handling.

Comment: @JNevill It indeed exited the loop no problem guys, thanks. Though is any way to overwriting the data formatless? I'm still having issues.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Because when deleting multiple cells at the same time it doesn't handle the instruction properly (memory error)

Comment: @Ali Instead of bypassing errors, code a loop to check one cell at a time.  Something like `for each myCell in intersect(Target,Columns("G") : do_your_code … :next myCell`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Will try now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it and it's date format proof (doesn't matter the order of DD or MM). Also added the suggestions in the comments. Thanks!

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("G")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Resume Next

    fecnacadd = Target.Address
    fecnac = Format(Target.Value, "YYYYMMDD")

    Target.Value = fecnac

    Columns("G").NumberFormat = "General"

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```